# Find, Replace inline file from multiple lists in Python

Tags: python

I have three python lists:

1. filePaths
2. textToFind
3. textToReplace

The lists are always equal lengths and in the correct order.

I need to open each file in filePaths, find the line in textToFind, and replace the line with textToReplace.  I have all the code that populates the lists.  I am stuck on making the replacements.  I have tried:

```
 for line in fileinput.input(filePath[i], inplace=1):
     sys.stdout.write(line.replace(find[i], replace[i]))
```

How do I iterate over each file to make the text replacements on each line that matches find?

Comment: You are only replacing one textToFind  in each filePath?  --->  Find ```textToFind[0]``` in ```filePaths[0]``` then replace with ```textToReplace[0]``` ; and  Find ```textToFind[1]``` in ```filePaths[1]``` then replace with ```textToReplace[1]```; ,,,, ?

Comment: Correct.  If a file has more than one textToReplace, the file is in the list x amount of times so the three lists are always in sync.

Comment: Why did you choose to use ```fileinput``` for your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to use the indices of the items in a sequence while iterating over that sequence, use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
for i, path in enumerate(filePath):
    for line in fileinput.input(path, inplace=1):
        sys.stdout.write(line.replace(find[i], replace[i]))
```

---

Another option would be to use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), which will give you one item from each sequence in order.

```
for path, find_text, replace_text in zip(filePath, textToFind, textToReplace):
    for line in fileinput.input(path, inplace=1):
        sys.stdout.write(line.replace(find_text, replace_text))
```

Note that for Python 2.x `zip` will produce a new list that can be iterated - so if the sequences you are zipping are huge it will consume memory.  Python 3.x `zip` produces an iterator so it doesn't have that feature.

---

With a normal file object you could read the entire file *into* a variable and perform the string replacement on the whole file at once.

---

Comment: Say there are 4 items in each list, the filePath for item 1 and 2 is the same because there are two different lines that need to be replaced in that file.  When I use zip, it does the correct replacements in the first file but in the second file, it replaces the third item twice.

Comment: @quietgrit, I don't know how that could happen and without all the details I cannot debug.  If you print ```path, find_text, replace_text``` in the outer loop it may give a clue.  I have never used ```fileinput``` and after looking over the docs I'm not sure we are using it as it was intended.

Comment: I see now that it's doing that because the textToFind is exactly the same twice in the same file so its replacing both lines.  So I guess I need to expand the textToFind to make sure it's always unique.

Answer (score 0):

I might do something like this without more information

```
for my_file in file_paths:
    with open(my_file, 'r') as cin, open(my_file, 'w') as cout:
        lines = cin.readlines() #store the file in mem so i can overwrite it.
        for line in lines:
            line = line.replace(find, replace) # change as needed
            cout.write(line)
```

Iterate over all the file paths, open the file up for reading and a separate one for writing. Store the files lines in a variable as in this code i will be overwriting the original file.  Do your replace, remember if there is nothing to replace python just leaves the line alone. Write the line back to file.

Answer (score 0):

You can read file to some temporary variable, make changes, and then write it back:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
with open('file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text.replace('aaa', 'bbb'))
```